Continued cash assistance and work requirements for individuals living off of cityfheps from shelter NYC?
Consider a scenario where an individual has been living in a shelter in New York City and is receiving assistance through the CityFHEPS (City Family Homelessness and Eviction Prevention Supplement) program. As part of the program requirements while in the shelter, this individual is mandated to work at least 40 hours per month and maintain an active cash assistance case.
Question:
Upon successfully transitioning from the shelter to a permanent home with the continued support of CityFHEPS, does the individual need to continue adhering to the initial program requirements, specifically:
Must the individual still work a minimum of 40 hours per month?
Is it necessary for the individual to keep their cash assistance case open even after moving to permanent housing?
